# Mongodb $lookup using with multiple criteria mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "Comment",
      let: {
        p_id: "$_id",
        d_id: "$data_id",

      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$p_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$data_id",
                    "$$d_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "subComment"
    }
  }
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/GbEgnVn3JSv
I am good at mongoplayground but tried to put there my thought

I want to fetch the comment of posts based on doc_id and post_id for mainComment query looks good to me but subcommand is not good. Please guide on this

Its simple as a post can have multiple comment need comment count base on Post.data._id which is equal to Comment.doc_id and Post._id is in Comment.post_id

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "mainComment" and "subComment" are, I believe you missed the dollar sign before them

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      main_comments_count: {
        $size: "$mainComment"
      },
      sub_comments_count: {
        $size: "$subComment"
      },

    }
  }
```

**Update**

What you did wrong in the playground is that you used `$data` in the `lookup.let` stage. `$data` is a document and the field you actually want to lookup is `$data._id`.

- sidenote: if you are looking up using just one field, you can simply use the `localField` and `foreign` in the lookup stage. Using `let` and `pipeline` is not necessary there.

```
db.setting.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "site",
      "let": {
        "pid": "$data._id"   //here
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$doc_id",
                "$$pid"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "subComment"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      countRecord: "$subComment"
    }
  }
])
```

i.e. this gives the same output

```
db.setting.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "site",
      localField: "data._id",
      foreignField: "doc_id",
      as: "subComment"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      countRecord: "$subComment"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Updated the code in playground it should returns me two out instead 0 see playgroundhttps://mongoplayground.net/p/GbEgnVn3JSv

Comment: @SunilDubey first, I think you will have to use ‘arrayElemAt’ to get the first document from an array. Second, inside the ‘eq’ you should use the ‘$post_id’ and ‘$doc_id’, as presented in the second collection

Comment: and what about if I want to display count  "data": [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("5e7cd2019b1c522b15cca6fe"),
          "url": "xyz.jpg",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 1000,
         "count": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("5e7cd2019b1c522b15cca6fd"),
          "url": "verr.jpg",
          "width": 601,
          "height": 1000
        }
      ]

Comment: You can see this match against data's _id 5e7cd2019b1c522b15cca6fe so it should add inside this array is this possible

Comment: I am not so good in mongodb if possible make correction in playground thanks

Comment: Sure, but I’m afk now. One thing you could try is that you can experiment more with $addFields, which is similar to $project except that you retains all other values. Debugging things stage by stage is a lot easier than debugging the whole aggregate pipeline altogether

Comment: Ok @chakwok once you back to computer please I'm also tryinging..

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/i1ku4VHmWMq Tried that way returns me countRecord : [] but it should display under data object and with count 2

Comment: Good work! It's very close already. I will update my answer to show the code